# how to get product id from which category in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, category-products, category-id

I want to get **product id** and also check that this **product's category id** and **name**. and also want to check that this **current category id** and **selected product's category id** equal or not...

Comment: Not able to understand what you are asking. Can you Improvise  your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can this code to get current product and its category

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

echo $product->getId();
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/

foreach($categories as $category){

    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);

    echo $cat->getName();
    }

?>
```

Comment: thankx vickey colors and Rita jose. :)

Comment: @Tushar did the above code worked?..If so please feel free to approve  the answer

Comment: i have have use it this code but problem generate in this code ihave different way use ... :) again thankx..:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Object Manager. Magento going to Deprecated objectManager in future. instead of this use inject method in constructor.

```
use Magento\Framework\Registry;    
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
protected $category;
protected $registry;

 public function __construct(    
        Registry $registry, 
        Category $category
    ) {
        $this->registry = $category;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
$product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
echo $product->getId();
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); 

foreach($categories as $category){
$cat = $this->category->load($category);

echo $cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: where did you get that the object manager is going to be deprecated? You are right, it should not be used, but can you provide a link where it says it's going to be deprecated?

Comment: In the following php file path vendor/magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/DocumentFactory.php. you can check line no 23.

Comment: That comment means the use of OM is deprecated in that class. Not the OM in general. If you take a closer look you will see that the OM is not used in the class. It's there for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: Its fine, using objectManager directly is not recommended  in Magento coding standard. while we check the code in MEQP2 , it will shows warning.

Comment: please check the following link. You may get helpful information. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Comment: That's exactly what I've been saying. The use of OM is not encouraged. But the OM is not deprecated. It means 2 different things.

Comment: thankx jothibasu and Marius :)